# TypeScript generics callback argument type inference

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm struggling with how to strongly type my Message broadcast Class

Essentially I want to send and listen to a limited set of Messages but It seems impossible to type the callbacks how the solution was designed:

Check in [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIQM4bgc08gbwChlTkByEOAN2BzjGAHsQA6DMOKMcgLkJJkhABwYALfhyigcg0gF8ANHIpVa9Ri1bQoTKHwFCR4yWGkgcyo2SgQ4GFvwAsABifIAPslcBmFUpVyOABXMDFWABsmHDwAE1ByZH5ia1JgjGhTc0t-InkiIjAAT2EUAEFqOGAIuAAjCIh0LFx8AF5kAGsIIqYYNExsPAwAbgLi0uQAGWAOCBBoDGR2lLIAbQBpZFBkCqqa+saBlowAXX4yqCg4IoAeAApRIqi4WP4mwcwNk4BKJYA+ZDUJjAWJ-PIFBA1LD9Zo4GSGMjCaSVSDICIzSDzKAYfjTWZYxbLFRCSg0OgMZhsDhcHj8VYnKypUnqClaHR6Az0xnWIKhcJRGIQeIgTkM-yjFTCYL1YAINEYuY3TYQAAemNii121TqDXex0UaCWMI+GC+fzuAFsjnh+OsDQg4BEIrVEB1+A9rs9Xmhfq0AUCQb8VtYwjNIgqCasrbCICdWFKMGI7g6nS6EB1vqMhPlJdL0XKMiBYkrkKr1ZrKtqDnqhgbUEaa591idzdGPraDY8vW8g8SyAgWBxkG2WnjMQsjaGMOH8Qso9bY1nUsAYJaF2O5hPWu0QMEnb3UkZbGBglAQEvrDnDyO8BuCawYHoAKKIJMRf5oj1PJgvb6ZgrZuCRDzAA7sauAyHc3wzpidzMuSmhUpw3DkAaUEfgQyADiADgNJE0RwQA-OQvzyP+oHgXCFhQTBcxwWoCGUuwyE8GhcC+gCmHYbhED4TgdxwPG4ikeREBgTWkHQei+L0WSGhMey+hsRxhBYYOTB4QKAmsLY9gsCJowURJ1FSRGcEhGEfFxAkykYWpOEabxWmCek0AGUQQA)

**Code:**

```js
interface Messages {
    'navigation.start': {
        path: string
    },
    'navigation.error': {
        path: string,
        reason: 404 | 403
    },
    'auth.loggedin' : {
        user: string,
    }
}

type AvailableMessages = keyof Messages;

type Listeners = {
    [K in AvailableMessages]: Array<(payload: Messages[K]) => void>
}

class Messaging {
    private listeners: Listeners = {
        'navigation.start': [],
        'navigation.error': [],
        'auth.loggedin': [],
    };

    public listen<K extends AvailableMessages, M = Messages[K]>(message: K, callback: (payload: M) => void) {
        this.listeners[message].push(callback);
    }

    public send<K extends AvailableMessages, M = Messages[K]>(message: K, payload: M) {
        const messageListeners = this.listeners[message];
        if(messageListeners == null) {
            return;
        }

        messageListeners.forEach(l => l(payload));

    }
}

new Messaging().listen('navigation.start', () => { console.log('?') });
new Messaging().listen('navigation.start', (a) => { console.log(a.path) });
new Messaging().listen('navigation.error', (a) => { console.log(a.reason) });
new Messaging().listen('auth.loggedin', (a) => { console.log(a.user) });
```

Comment: You might find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62623637/r-could-be-instantiated-with-an-arbitrary-type-which-could-be-unrelated-to-re

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with the method signature

```
public listen<K extends AvailableMessages, M = Messages[K]>(
     message: K,
     callback: (payload: M) => void
)
```

First, there are no bounds on the type of `M`, so I could do

```
new Messaging().listen<'navigation.start', number>('navigation.start', 3)
```

which is not type safe.

Second, even if the type parameter `M` was removed (i.e `callback` was of type  `(payload: Messages[K]) => void`)

```
new Messaging()
    .listen<'navigation.start' | 'navigation.error'>(
        'navigation.start',
        ({ reason }) => console.log("navigation.error listener called")
    )
```

which would violate type safety.

---

Ideally, there would be some way to specify that the generic parameter should be *exactly* one of the keys (i.e no union types). To my knowledge, there is not really a good way to do this in TypeScript.

It is possible to create a type that converts union types to `never` like so by abusing distributive conditional types:

```
type SingleHelper<T, V> = T extends any 
    ? [V] extends [T] 
        ? V 
        : never 
    : never;
type Single<T> = SingleHelper<T, T>
```

using this type, `Single<"hello">` evaluates to `"hello"`, but `Single<"hello" | "goodbye">` evaluates to `never`.

However, even if we used this type in the signature of `listen`, i.e if we wrote

```
public listen<K extends AvailableMessages>(
     message: Single<K>,
     callback: (payload: Messages[Single<K>]) => void
)
```

TypeScript would not be able to infer that the type only includes the exact keys. While you would still run into type errors in the body, it would force callers to use the function correctly.