# Type 'T | undefined' is not assignable to type 'T'. 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T | undefined'

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

WARNING: TypeScript noob question.

I am learning TypeScript via Udemy (https://www.udemy.com/course/typescript-for-professionals). While trying some sample code I get an error in Code:

```
class Queue4<T> {
    private data: Array<T> = [];
    push( item: T ):void {        this.data.push(item)  }
    pop(          ):T    { return this.data.shift() } // error: Type 'T | undefined' is not assignable to type 'T'. 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T | undefined'.ts(2322)
}
const myQueue4 = new Queue4<number>();
myQueue4.push( 123 )
myQueue4.push( 234 )
console.log( myQueue4.pop().toPrecision(1) )
```

Other searches on this error don't help -- samples are too complex. The most useful thing I have come across is this explanation from @jcalz:

> Generic functions in TypeScript act as a function representing every possible specification of its generic type parameters, since it's the caller of the function that specifies the type parameter, not the implementer.

['R' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Response<Command>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62623637/r-could-be-instantiated-with-an-arbitrary-type-which-could-be-unrelated-to-re)

Even if I remove the code after the class TS still complains. I get the same error for both "target": "es5" and "target": "es2015".

1. Why is this happening?
2. How do I fix this?

Comment: It has a good reason for complaining - `shift` can return `undefined`, so your method should be `pop():T|undefined`  too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first options:

```
class Queue4<T> {
    private data: Array<T> = [];
    push(item: T): void {
        this.data.push(item)
    }
    pop(): T {
        // At runtime shift() should return undefined in case of empty array.
        // That's why, if you want to return T you should tell TS to exclude undefined from resulting type
        // by means of ! operator
        return this.data.shift()!;
    }
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECKCuBTJAWAPAFQHzQN4ChojoAHAJwEsA3MAF0WgBM6wAuaAQTLLAE9McAXmgBtALoBuQsRLwIACwAUFegFt2GAJTsqAewqM804sVryKEAHTNaYS7IXK1m49AC%20rkrpKLt0DEYmJgD0wZy00GTwAHa0FKoMChQAZrS%200MBg0ZGItPBk2TGMiMkU0YiGZRmQDLrJ0IiqJLS80GDcfJauIWEY8nQA5DAA7vK8ADTQKdC8uvDQw1kRtLo5eQX%20M3PQCnMghvQgIP4AytArDQAeoPDF0EUlZRXQyWS6qjkQ8CBx0QDm514JEQ3WIoWgACNWgksjA6tAAITQbyIHgrMigohkXL5bJmCzWFiWJKpXwIqQmDwefDAXTRCARVS8BDIRAoaDCcrDOBIVBoaLwVQQ1FYXxSJks1D2ORKaAARgATABmaAuCW8tnSxzQZXsly0%20m6ECISwgXR-RTQdWslD2by%20SwrAAK2OAFgodMUcs0qqAA)

The second option:

```
class Queue4<T> {
    private data: Array<T> = [];
    push(item: T): void {
        this.data.push(item)
    }
    pop(): T | undefined {
        // At runtime shift() should return undefined in case of empty array.
        // That's why ypou should declare union nullable type T | undefined as a resulting type
        return this.data.shift();
    }
}

const myQueue4 = new Queue4<number>();
// And here you should explicitly check the result to refine type
const result = myQueue4.pop();
if (result) {
    console.log(result.toPrecision(1));
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECKCuBTJAWAPAFQHzQN4ChojoAHAJwEsA3MAF0WgBM6wAuaAQTLLAE9McAXmgBtALoBuQsRLwIACwAUFegFt2GAJTsqAewqM804sVryKEAHTNaYS7IXK1m49AC%20rkrpKLt0DNAAPtDwAHaMiABmFKGIhgQmJgD0SZy00GRhtBSqDAoUkbS%200Aq68CCGZIi08GShIeFRMXHQMdDAkAy6kdCIqiS0vNBg3HyWrsmpGPJ0AOQwAO7yQ7xe8CXyZRVMiKAjDGEUuvWh5eAARiAMgyQMAcFhEdGxhpDDGYgQ5dmhAObQN0QE2IVRqdQB5isNjs%20UKvikJg8HnwwGOEHSql4CGQiBQ0GEsQWcCQqDQp1U50QZCw8PwKU44Wg8ipDF4ZQ2W0MiAAHiQQBRgCoQENgMzgABrCEMKpfEDpWi6D7Pa6rIGo0Loj6y9LCTHY1D2by0grQRQy76aIwmdUQXRXSwgXS-M2fb6WBUABSqgogR1CigAjJpNFIPEA)

Comment: I like the simplicity of the first solution. The second solution seems to be more work without an obvious (to me) benefit. FYI, the TS Playground links resulted in mangled code. Fixed with copy-and-paste. Thank-you for a quick and succinct answer.

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue and spent some time on it. This looks related with Linter Checks Strictness.
Try:

"noUncheckedIndexedAccess": false,

in your tsconfig.json

It worked with my case.