# Generic method implementation from lambda definition

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm struggling to figure out even how to search for an answer to this so I thought I'd post it here in the hope that it's particularly easy to answer...

I have a type definition as follows:

```js
export type Handler = <T>(input: Input, output: Output<T>) => Promise<void>;
```

And a method that takes multiple `Handler` implementations as an argument:

```js
function MyMethod(handlers: {[name: string]: Handler}) { ... }
```

Could someone help me understand how I define `T` for each implementation of `Handler` when I'm calling `MyMethod`?

Something like:

```js
MyMethod({
    "one" : (input, output) => { ... }, //Here T should be string for example
    "two" : (input, output) => { ... }  //Here T should be number for example
});
```

**Update**

I managed to get it working using typecasting on the method implementation... is this the right thing to do here?

Changed the definition of `Handler` to:

```js
export type Handler<T | any> = (input: Input, output: Output<T> => Promise<void>;
```

Then called `MyMethod` like this:

```js
MyMethod({
    "one" : <Handler<string>>(input, output) => { ... }, //output is now Output<string>
    "two" : <Handler<number>>(input, output) => { ... }  //output is now Output<number>
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: I guess this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62625899/12044155

Comment: I don't _think_ it does... for each implementation of `Handler` the generic type `Output<T>` needs a different definition for `T` - I'm not sure that link helps with that

Comment: Please share reproducible example with `Input` and `Output` types