# Type 'Record<string, unknown>' is missing the following properties from type 'MyObject': one, two

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I’m having a typescript issue where I’m trying to define a generic function that can accept an object-like argument, but I keep getting an error that doesn’t make sense:

```js
type MyFunc = <T extends Record<string, unknown>>(obj: T) => any;

type MyObject = {
  one: string,
  two: number,
}

const myGetter: MyFunc = (obj: MyObject) => console.log(obj);
// ERROR: Type 'Record<string, unknown>' is missing the following properties from type 'MyObject': one, two
```

Furthermore, `MyObject` *does*, in fact, extend `Record<string, unknown>`:

```js
type TrueFalse = MyObject extends Record<string, unknown> ? true : false;
// true
```

Here's the tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

I'm on `"typescript": "^4.1.3",`

Here's the typescript sandbox: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiBXAdgYygXigHgCpQgA9gJkATAZygCUJUB7AJzOwuEYEtkBzAGihQBrZPQDuyAHwSAFPQBGAKwBcUXAEpMEqAENkIANwAoQ6EiwQAeUV1gmKAG9DUKPWQQVbTj15OowUfQqyIgAtnIQjD4AvsYMyGxQISAA4hDAJIwqcEhodrKKWZbWqMAaGFpxFPQANhAAdNX03PkKavpAA

Comment: `one` and `two` aren't defined anywhere in `Record<string, unknown>`.

Comment: Shouldn't normal objects be able to extend `Record<string, unknown>`?

Comment: The error is a valid one.  *Callers* specify the type of a generic function's type parameter; `<T extends Record<string, unknown>>(obj: T) => any` means that the caller chooses `T`, not the implementer.  So it's not safe to implement something that only accepts `MyObject`, or else [this sort of thing](https://tsplay.dev/wX2a9m) happens.  It seems like you're making the wrong thing generic here, but you don't have much in the way of an example to go to.  I'd say this is sort of a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62623637/2887218).

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wOze6W) meet your needs instead? (Note how the scope of the generic type parameter moved from the function call signature to the type declaration, so that the implementer chooses it and not the caller.)  If so I can write up an answer; if not, please let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: @jcalz This approach won't work with an interface since it will miss the index signature, any reason not to use <T extends object>?

Comment: Hmm I guess I never saw the reply here saying I should post an answer.  @ShaharKazaz you should definitely use `T extends object` , there's no reason not to unless you have an overactive linter.