# How to type this Symbol Iterator implementation in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get this working JavaScript (but not mine :P) pass typescript type checking. Maybe it's just late in the day but I could use some help.

```js
class GPUTexture {}

class BaseState<T> {
    webgpuObject: T | null;

    constructor() {
        this.webgpuObject = null;
    }
}

class TextureState extends BaseState<GPUTexture> {
   name = "foo";
}

interface CaptureStateBase<GPUType> {
    webgpuObject: GPUType | null;
}

class ObjectRegistry<GPUType extends Object, CaptureState extends CaptureStateBase<GPUType>> {
    iterating: boolean;
    dataMap: WeakMap<GPUType, CaptureState>;
    objects: WeakRef<GPUType>[];

    constructor() {
        this.dataMap = new WeakMap();
        this.objects = [];
        this.iterating = false;
    }

    add(obj: GPUType, data: CaptureState) {
        if (this.iterating) {
            throw new Error('Mutating Registry while iterating it.');
        }

        this.dataMap.set(obj, data);
        this.objects.push(new WeakRef(obj));
        data.webgpuObject = obj;
    }

    get(obj: GPUType) {
        return this.dataMap.get(obj);
    }

    [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<CaptureState> {
        let i = 0;
        this.iterating = true;

        return {
            registry: this,
            next() {
                while (i < this.registry.objects.length) {
                    const obj = this.registry.objects[i++].deref();
                    if (obj === undefined) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    return { value: this.registry.get(obj), done: false };
                }
                this.registry.iterating = false;
                return { done: true };
            },
        };
    }
}

const textures = new ObjectRegistry<GPUTexture, TextureState>();
for (const tex of textures) {
  console.log(tex.name);
}
```

I'd try to simplify the code but I'm not sure I understand the error. I see 2 errors actually. One is, typescript seems confused about `this` inside `next`. I complains about `this.registry` not existing

The other is

> (method) Iterator<CaptureState, any, undefined>.next(...args: [] | [undefined]): IteratorResult<CaptureState, any>
>
> Type '() => { value: any; done: false; } | { done: true; value?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type '(...args: [] | [undefined]) => IteratorResult<CaptureState, any>'.
>
> Type '{ value: any; done: false; } | { done: true; value?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<CaptureState, any>'.
>
> Type '{ done: true; value?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<CaptureState, any>'.
>
> Type '{ done: true; value?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'IteratorReturnResult'.
>
> Property 'value' is optional in type '{ done: true; value?: undefined; }' but required in type 'IteratorReturnResult'.(2322)

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/FAYwNghgzlAEDiAFAqgFQKYA8AuBXATurAN4C+wokMsAQtOgMrYTboA8qAfCcLH7AHd0AIwDmAB1wB5YQCt0IbAC5YqWAB9YAO1xgwAbgr9YIAPZao2fLkWn8ACgCUPY8ewALAJZQAdELGSMvKKsAC82roGvPzk5JTQcBg4BIzMrLBYrFoAJnB0UKks7EhomSncxNF8WhAAtkShAEQAZqamjYZxnlqs+M0QIEQAwhDieIRMRfnFKKgAnuLoFVWCIhLScgrKCLMLRJo6ep0U4AmwQVsASuii3lZzbCXzixk46DlwF4oANLAjYylJulMu9cn9RuNCqxpo9dotOMtjJ5eixuqIVMI2mB0BAtIZjNkWBAALKjFQAdRxAGtSeJYWg9r9-pCgUt8fxTJtFFAKdTrs16c8lgBtAC6hhWZgsVhs2DsThcrj4Hm8PkJzFpYW06AEsEpEBpoyc7KVKt8nOC2Dg4TFJtcZp8yPQ+FRWlEWv6YAKdrixgg2Wy9gtKiejNg6ogKmZgLS6GclSVfE8zVg9gdTpd2DR8ZWidgHnwpl1Wh1sAAovhCw4AOTE3BpNGwa63Sz4OaCLzY2AZ13u5E+auOO3GX2Jh0R2k+ArYINyX4Roe5-gOi1bXySKDuewl3X6qn82eyRyLvMRvxrQJc7Bai0+oz8UToGfBnYMxY5vOEcZafNeXwT0YfEfZ85BPGJ7z4YUGDmWpMTAR0UTlfBRScFQAEkUWEbEMOdFg7DYaMJljRFE2xa9PC1AAGYdlz-BDcKzN0tRldAJU-J8CB-BM834QgW3uFQzW+JclRLHAFW4njXAETsiHsCi2F-VU+LuNsfFXbkfGxN0PA-KSeKlSxYAtZi6JU1s5nUq8oGFTwAGo7NFNVnXQZpjRE-SkxTQ8wlCcJcByVzunQbI9M8qSpUY3BWI8zzyHCxMv04khYAANwgMBosEsyblUyzgMPRx53MdAVE9ApYFIGipPihKlN8cz7nozNG3CcqYrq2AkvwLjwxKwTrCIKrYpiYS82GkdgDiQzr1YZJCGtbVdS+bBmzywUykIX4khZYj3NafBUxm-MsGMlM5shKAwpMcwoFMbEtNMUQ0ywHwanqRdSCAA)

I tried to fix the first one by moving `next` up like this

```
class GPUTexture {}

class BaseState<T> {
    webgpuObject: T | null;

    constructor() {
        this.webgpuObject = null;
    }
}

class TextureState extends BaseState<GPUTexture> {
    name = "foo";
}

interface CaptureStateBase<GPUType> {
    webgpuObject: GPUType | null;
}

class ObjectRegistry<GPUType extends Object, CaptureState extends CaptureStateBase<GPUType>> {
    iterating: boolean;
    dataMap: WeakMap<GPUType, CaptureState>;
    objects: WeakRef<GPUType>[];

    constructor() {
        this.dataMap = new WeakMap();
        this.objects = [];
        this.iterating = false;
    }

    add(obj: GPUType, data: CaptureState) {
        if (this.iterating) {
            throw new Error('Mutating Registry while iterating it.');
        }

        this.dataMap.set(obj, data);
        this.objects.push(new WeakRef(obj));
        data.webgpuObject = obj;
    }

    get(obj: GPUType) {
        return this.dataMap.get(obj);
    }

    [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<CaptureState> {
        let i = 0;
        this.iterating = true;

        const next = () => {
            while (i < this.objects.length) {
                const obj = this.objects[i++].deref();
                if (obj === undefined) {
                    continue;
                }
                return { value: this.get(obj), done: false };
            }
            this.iterating = false;
            return { done: true };
        };

        return { next };
    }
}

const textures = new ObjectRegistry<GPUTexture, TextureState>();
for (const tex of textures) {
  console.log(tex.name);
}
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/FAYwNghgzlAEDiAFAqgFQKYA8AuBXATurAN4C+wokMsAQtOgMrYTboA8qAfCcLH7AHd0AIwDmAB1wB5YQCt0IbAC5YqWAB9YAO1xgwAbgr9YIAPZao2fLkWn8ACgCUPY8ewALAJZQAdELGSMvKKsAC82roGvPzk5JTQcBg4BIzMrLBYrFoAJnB0UKks7EhomSncxNF8WhAAtkThAEQAZqamjYZxnlqs+M0QIEQAwhDieIRMRfnFKKgAnuLoFVWCIhLScgrKCLMLRJo6ep0U4AmwQVsASuii3lZzbCXzixk46DlwF4oANLAjYylJulMu9cn9RuNCqxpo9dotOMtjJ5eixuqIVMI2mB0BAtIZjNkWBAALKjFQAdRxAGtSeJYWg9r9-pCgUt8fxTJtFFAKdTrs16c8lgBtAC6hhWZgsVhs2DsThcrj4Hm8PkJzFpYW06AEsEpEBpoyc7KVKt8nOC2Dg4TFJtcZp8yPQ+FRWlEWv6YAKdrixgg2Wy9gtKiejNg6ogKmZgLS6GclSVfE8zVg9gdTpd2DR8ZWidgHnwpl1Wh1sAAovhCw4AOTE3BpNGwa63Sz4OaCLzY2AZ13u5E+auOO3GX2Jh0R2k+ArYINyX4Roe5-gOi1bXySKDuewl3X6qn82eyRyLvMRvxrQJc7Bai0+oz8UToGfBnYMxY5vOEcZafNeXwT0YfEfZ85BPGJ7z4YUGDmWpMTAR0UTlfBRScFQAEkUWEbEMOdFg7DYaMJljRFE2xa9PC1AAGYdlz-BDcKzN0tRldAJTzKVLG1HAtQVUISLzPgBE7Ih7Aothf1VVduR8bE3Q8D8BKVDjrwtZi6Kkq1hU8ABqbTRTVZ10GaY0l0U5NU1U0IrNgXAciM7p0GyBTFPY8xGNwVjTIE8gXNcL8CB-YhYAANwgMAPJUB1gMPRx53MdAVE9ApYFIGilR8lz00QxtwiSzzfP8-BAvDeLIusIhUq8yqvMK4qS24yqR2AOJlPzMpCGtbVdS+bBmzuNtBXa9BfiSFliJM1p8FTVrWEwWBTBTWbISgZyTHMKBTGxGTTFENMsB8Gp6kXcggA)

That solves the first error but not the second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing a separate `this.registry` as a custom value on an iterator object is odd and can cause problems. It'd be easier to ditch that entirely and just use an arrow function and the outer `this`. That way, the typing for it will *just work* - your arrow function is the right idea.

```
next: () => {
    while (i < this.objects.length) {
        const obj = this.objects[i++].deref();
        // ...
```

After that, there's just one more warning due to the [typing here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62623637/r-could-be-instantiated-with-an-arbitrary-type-which-could-be-unrelated-to-re):

```
[Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<CaptureState> {
```

which can be fixed by specifying that the `this` is the same as the class that was instantiated, and letting TypeScript infer the iterator type on its own.

```
[Symbol.iterator](this: ObjectRegistry<GPUType, CaptureState>) {
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ssl=42&ssc=69&pln=42&pc=5#code/MYGwhgzhAEDiAKBVAKgUwB4BcCuAnV0A3gL4CwAUBaJDAEKSoDKmYmqAPMgHxEXT-QA7qgBGAcwAO2APIiAVqmCYAXNGTQAPtAB22ECADcFPgOAB7bREy5sSs7gAUASl7kB76JgAWASwgA6YXEpWQUlaABeHT1DE34ycgSqcCg1DBx8ZlYCdNRtABM6Biy2dgQUdLxUHhJjch9tNlwAMzBgAgBhMAkMphY2eggOcuQATwlq13cgyRl5RRU4JDGJzWj9I0S66lTQhYAlVDE-a1Gy5fGcrDzC6D2lABpoLp6qkqu2ApgX3vfB4YuEy4NTi0B8TVYDTEqhEZjMIFQYG0m3c+VYYAAst1VAB1REAayxEnOKEuTx+b361RRAjM8yUEFxBMOzRJK2qAG0ALqbUHmSzWWyYezOKYefjePz+NEsImRHSoQTQPFgQndZw08WSgJ0sKYGBRbmajza-zg1C4SHaMTy1ogIbGpJuARgfL5By61QjMnQGVgVQUzJUlyEUHuHzNaAOU3my2YKEhsPizxeXBmJXaRXQACiuDTjgA5BjsP0odBDscrLhRkJfAiwRD49aG-4C05je4ncmU1K-UT-ENMB75E8-e2kxLfDr6fr-FIIF4HJmlSr8Szh3InOPneK-YFRLN7ph5brHXV3GJUEPPUtSRNEzuPPgMtoewE+91-Jfr-Jt53zwIHKMKMAC2sIgGajb2Fy0ZTqoR4Vic1Zsj6gZ9NkXAPt2CLHj48oAAwdgIMaNmWUSCqgvKPu4z54K+obUcm+CVqcqjag8E4eJmWCqKKEQgox3b8IIdYEA4eHsG+-i6gsAQIta3hYUJyn8lY0C6vKpoyQyHI+AA1HpXLShaqDNBqnHKfwEZRhpER2dA2AFKZDSoPkSmWZZ-JNtglEWZZCQed2tG4PR0AAG5gCAPlsVOX5XhuTijhYqCqHaQzQMQRHKQFgWTlKsZWjaURpb5glCcFoX5MlbE2KgTwRVFKUOU5zQufkGVZR4xAcWVmWggkTqqcebBYFUBoKkqCFHEhZwjJU+BPGgo1BhhGpAA)

---

The

> Property 'value' is optional in type '{ done: true; value?: undefined; }' but required in type 'IteratorReturnResult'.(2322)

can be fixed by changing

```
return { done: true };
```

to

```
return { done: true, value: undefined };
```

but doesn't look necessary.

Comment: Thank you! One more question: If I go try to actually use this iterator in a `for (o of collection)` it will complain the `o` might be undefined. But `o` will never be undefined. What would I have to do to get typescript to recognize that? [example](https://shorturl.at/jBLQU). Though it got the type errors mentioned before, it didn't get those type errors when using it until I switched to this solution.

Comment: I suspect that the type can't be removed safely naturally; `{ done: true }`'s type would need to be changed (for example, to include a dummy object). You'll also need to assert that `this.get(obj)` in the loop will definitely find something; use `!` to assert that it's non-nullish.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense to me. An iterator that always has to be checked becuse for the last return value, `value` won't be set isn't a very useful iterator. There must be some way to tell it. I put the `!` for `this.get(obj)` and I can see that it's typed as never null but it didn't stop the error.

Comment: For a more minimal example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAsAKBnmA2gMoCeAtvCADYB0AllAKYBOAhlCMwLoAUAlBhz5hMKo1h1UMAAwBuISLzNxAV2ZhBuRSLCMAHlABcMfqgB8m7VZh0AZickAeGAGYBWLdevKoajehgAN1YqFUZjOgAaGAATcHCYWxCIRhgAXwUvYQzPLKVVdQxY+OMoZjD0+VyrNMjMkTSq7JwcnFtOE1BIWFgQewREdxagA Yeah, you'd think there'd be a more elegant approach. Just in case there isn't, at the end, you can do `return { done: true, value: null as unknown as CaptureState };` It results in no TypeScript errors, but it's ugly.

Comment: That example has the same issue: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAsAKBnmA2gMoCeAtvCADYB0AllAKYBOAhlCMwLoAUAlBhz5hMKo1h1UMAAwBuISLzNxAV2ZhBuRSLCMAHlABcMfqgB8m7VZh0AZickAeGAGYBWLdevKoajehgAN1YqFUZjOgAaGAATcHCYWxCIRhgAXwUvYQzPLKVVdQxY+OMoZjD0+VyrNMjMkTSq7JwcnFtOE1BIWFgQewREd3quiGpGGioQAHMeKBoOADE6PUYYngBGPj4qtKA  But, yeah, returning a bogus last value fixes it.