# How to create function with generic return type in interface and specify it at initialization? Angular/Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to specify different return type when creating an array of TableDefinition.

I have created a model like this:

```
export interface TableDefinition<T>{
  field: string;
  value: <K>(order: T) => K;
}
```

Initialization:

```
this.cols = [
  { field: 'id', value: (obj: Person) => obj.Id}
];
```

I get this error: *'K' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'string'.*

Is it possible to specify return type at initialization or any other ways to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['R' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Response<Command>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62623637/r-could-be-instantiated-with-an-arbitrary-type-which-could-be-unrelated-to-re)

Comment: The above question may be hard to digest, but essentially, the generic parameter on `value` should be there or exist at all: https://tsplay.dev/WPzkqN