# Typescript generic help - 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I've got this example function which converts an array of objects to a single object:

```js
const exampleFunction = <T extends Record<string, string>>(): T => {
    const someData = [{name: 'user', value: 'test-user'}, {name: 'password', value: 'password123'}]

    const mappedData = someData.reduce((prev, curr) => {
        const key = curr.name

        return {
            ...prev,
            [key]: curr.value
        }
    }, {})

    return mappedData
}
```

And then I want to call the function like so:

```js
const {user, password} = exampleFunction<{user: string, password: string}>()
```

However I get the TS error:

`Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'T'. '{}' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Record<string, string>'`

I thought the purpose of `extends` is to enforce the generic type to be an object, so can't quite get my head around why TS is not happy. What am I missing here?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgDwIYFsAOAbOAxArmYKAS3BgF4YAeAFXgSjjABMIYAlOUAJycui6JgA5gBoY-QUIB8UgBQBKAFwxaZKTADeAKBi6YoSLAggUcACJIoScjADaGsKjjKA5LghwuLsQDckGXGcYFwZoAFp3TxcAXzEHJ1c0JAgIAHcQHm8YPwCglySU9J4ARgAmAGYYgF0tHT0DaBgUJDQ0OCYLKxtjU06kADoudtxgOFlZNCGfMWBcLi55cnVtPVX9cEaAazgATxtZ%20f7HU1q6tZghqDmwTTPzvX7Hybhpu-u7bZ2q5QOufpzAm89NE7rFNNF5LVVpdrk0Wm0OpYkFoQbUGrANJEuGICmkMkxojZEKhMDh8IQSGBKJiPFxlBJhDjkniePSoAJhNE5JCtA0QFh%20hgQEJZFimYV8fIgA)

Comment: The *caller* chooses the generic type arguments, not the implementer.  Nothing stops a caller from writing `const {a} = exampleFunction<{a: string}>()` and then `a.toUpperCase()` which explodes at runtime.  The implementation cannot possibly return a value of a type `T` chosen by the caller since the function doesn't accept any arguments related to `T` (or any arguments at all, for that matter).   So you get an error.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62625899/2887218

Comment: what do you think the compiler can infer in terms of what the type of `mappedData` is?